# Javascript highest number in each tr, skip 3 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, that will add a class to the highest number in each tr.

I want it to skip the first 3 columns and not search them.  And then if there are multiple of the highest then bold those too.

I will paste code here as well as fiddle.

**HTML**

```
    <style>
        .highest {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>

<table width="300">
    <tr>
        <th>no</th>
        <th>no</th>
        <th>no</th>
        <th>yes</th>
        <th>yes</th>
        <th>yes</th>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>10.5</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>9.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12.0</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>13.5</td>
        <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>160</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>115</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>160</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>145</td>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>151</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.max = function(callback) {
        var max = null,
            maxIndex = null;

        this.each(function() {
            var value = callback.call(this);
            if (+value === value) {
                if (!max || value > max) {
                    max = value;
                    maxIndex = $(this).index();
                }
            }

        });
        return max !== null ? this.eq(maxIndex) : $();
    };
}(jQuery));


$('tr').each(function() 
    $(this).children('td').max(function() {
        var value = +$(this).text();
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            return value;
        }
    }).addClass('highest');
});
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/96/

Comment: I would rather use `parseInt($(this).text())` instead of `+$(this).text()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a selector as a parameter to the plugin, and filter by that :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.max = function(selector) {
        var elems = $();
        this.each(function() {
            var max = 0,
                ele = $(this).find(selector).each(function(i,el) {
                var n  = parseFloat($(el).text());
                if ( n > max ) max = n;
            }).filter(function() {
                return parseFloat($(this).text()) === max;
            });
            elems = elems.add(ele);
        });
        return elems;
    };
}(jQuery));


$('tr').max('td:gt(2)').addClass('highest');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/65S7N/98/)

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first 3 columns, use:

```
$(this).children('td').filter(function(i) {
    return i > 2;
}).max(...)
```

The filter function receives the zero-based position of the element within the collection.

If you want to highlight multiple entries that have the max value, `maxIndex` needs to be an array, not a single value. When `value === max`, push the current index onto the array. Or make it a jQuery collection of elements, rather than indexes, and add the current element to it.

Comment: I changed `$(this).children('td').max(function() {` to `$(this).children('td').filter(function(i) {
    return i > 2;
}).max(function() {` and doesn't bold anything now.  Sorry new to javascript

Comment: the problem is `this.eq(maxIndex)`. `maxIndex` is relative to all the children of the parent node, but `this.eq()` just counts relative to the collection, which excludes the first 3 columns. This is why you should save the element instead of the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var this = $(this);
    var max = -Infinity;
    var indexes = [];
    this.find('td:gt(2)').each(function(index){
        var this_num = ($(this).text() >> 0);
        if ( max < this_num ) {
            max = this_num;
            indexes = [index];
        } else if (max == this_num ) {
            indexes.push(this_num);
        }
    });
    $(indexes).each(function(index){
        this.find('td:eq('+index+')').addClass('highest');
    });
});
```

should work.. haven't tested :|